# Como eu retorno um caractere de uma string na função em Python com biblioteca Websockets e json?

Tags: python, json, string, funções, websocket

Eu sou novo em Python e tenho uma dúvida, que estou tentando resolver faz tempo.

Eu estou criando um programa de análise de ticks de um site de investimento, e quero extrair o valor de
uma determinada string. Eu até consegui chegar no caractere que quero extrair, porém não consigo retornar ele para a main.

Segue abaixo o código principal para vocês entenderem o que quero fazer:

```
import websocket
import json

def on_open(ws):
    json_data = json.dumps({'ticks':'R_100'})
    ws.send(json_data)

def on_message(ws, message):
    print('ticks update: %s' % message)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    apiUrl = "wss://ws.binaryws.com/websockets/v3?app_id=1089"
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(apiUrl, on_message = on_message, on_open = on_open)
    ws.run_forever()
```

Quero extrair da função os números destacados em amarelo, que peguei da IDLE:

[image: IDLE do programa inicial]

Eu até consegui extrair o número que quero, conforme imagem abaixo, e consigo imprimir ele na função:

```
import websocket
import json

def on_open(ws):
    json_data = json.dumps({'ticks': 'R_100'})
    ws.send(json_data)

def on_message(ws, message):
    a=""
    a=message[235]
    print(message)
    print('a = ', a)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    apiUrl = "wss://ws.binaryws.com/websockets/v3?app_id=1089"
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(apiUrl, on_message = on_message, on_open = on_open)
    ws.run_forever()
```

[image: IDL2 - Imprimindo número desejado]

Mas eu não consigo extrair para fora da função, pois quero trabalhar com este número na main, visto que na função ele continua com o mesmo número e não da para usar os if.

```
import websocket
import json

def on_open(ws):
    json_data = json.dumps({'ticks': 'R_100'})
    ws.send(json_data)

def on_message(ws, message):
    a=""
    a=message[235]
    return a

if __name__ == "__main__":
    apiUrl = "wss://ws.binaryws.com/websockets/v3?app_id=1089"
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(apiUrl, on_message = on_message, on_open = on_open)
    tick=""
    tick=on_message
    print(tick)
    ws.run_forever()
```

A IDLE imprime isso, ao invés de imprimir o número desejado: <function on_message at 0x00000195A1D4C310>

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Alguém consegue ajudar?

Comment: Oi Luiz, não tem como você retornar o valor de `a` da função, mas tem outras coisas que você pode fazer. Eu posso te ajudar com isso, mas o que você pretende fazer com esse caracter na main?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Antes de responder sua pergunta vou tentar esclarecer algumas coisas sobre o que acontece nesse código que aparentemente você não domina completamente. A primeira é o que acontece quando você chama o `websocket.WebSocketApp()`: nesse ponto você cria uma instância da classe WebSocketAPP, mas você ainda não executa nenhuma ação de enviar ou receber dado. Por esse motivo tentar imprimir uma mensagem agora não tem sentido, já que nenhuma mensagem foi recebida.

O segundo ponto é o que é o `on_message`. Existe a função `on_message`, que você definiu, que recebe dois parâmetros (uma instância do WebSocketApp e uma mensagem) e existe o parâmetro `on_message` interno do WebSocketApp. Esse parâmetro define qual função vai ser executada toda vez que o App receber algum dado. Você poderia mudar mudar o nome da sua função, por exemplo:

```
def a_cada_mensagem(ws, message):
    a=message[235]
    ...
```

e depois criar o seu App com `ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(apiUrl, on_message = a_cada_mensagem)`. Isso significa que quem vai chamar a função explicitada no parâmetro `on_message` é o websocket e não o usuário. Sendo assim, o valor que a função retorna não fica disponível para o usuário. Tem como mudar isso alterando as funções "embutidas" da classe WebSocketApp, mas vai por mim quando eu digo que você não quer fazer isso. Mas calma que existe uma solução.

A última coisa que você precisa entender antes da solução é o que acontece no `ws.run_forever()`. Nesse comando sim o seu App vai fazer troca de dados do WebSocket framework. Mas aqui ele vai entrar em um loop infinito e, até que esse loop seja quebrado, nenhum código que venha depois dessa linha vai ser executado. Então nesse ponto você pode ter a mensagem, mas ela vai mudar a cada loop e você não consegue seguir no `main`. Então se você quer fazer alguma coisa com as mensagens só tem duas alternativas:

**1: Operar as mensagens dentro da função on_message(ws, message):** Já que você não consegue voltar pro main, você pode fazer o que precisar dentro dessa função, inclusive chamar outras funções. Aqui você tem acesso à variável que você quer, então por que não usar ela aqui?

**2: Quebrar o loop:** se você quer fazer algo no main, mas não pode porque está preso no loop infinito então a alternativa é quebrar o loop em algum momento. Vamos supor que você queira rodar o loop três vezes e depois parar e analizar quais foras as respostas que você obteve. Nesse caso você vai precisar de um contador global, para saber quantas vezes já rodou, e uma lista para poder armazenar as variáveis que você quer. Sendo uma lista, você não precisa se preocupar em retornar ela. Basta acessar depois no main:

```
import websocket
import json

def on_open(ws):
    json_data = json.dumps({'ticks': 'R_100'})
    ws.send(json_data)

a_list = []
count = 0
def on_message(ws, message):
    global count
    if count == 3:
        ws.close()
    else:
        a=message[235]
        a_list.append(a)
        count += 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    apiUrl = "wss://ws.binaryws.com/websockets/v3?app_id=1089"
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(apiUrl, on_message = on_message, on_open = on_open)
    ws.run_forever()
    print(a_list)
```

Você pode usar a condição que você quiser para interromper o loop

Comment: eu tentei trabalhar na própria função, porém, eu quis definir algumas condições que dependeriam de outro loop, sendo que utilizando o mesmo loop, ele só consideraria um valor para as minhas condições.

O que deu certo, foi a tua segunda sugestão ao trabalhar com a quebra de loop e listas, isso funcionou para o meu caso. Obrigado pela ótima resposta!